# An entire function that only has simple zeroes at the positive squares

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, weierstrass-factorization

By the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem, every entire function f can be represented as a product involving its zeroes.

Moreover, if $\{ a_n \}$ is the sequence of zeroes of $f$ then $\displaystyle f(z) = z\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n(z/a_n)$ where $E_n$ is the elementary factor (a.k.a canonical factor) defined as $E_n(z) = (1-z)exp({\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z^k}{k}})$

Putting in the conditions for positive squares, I got the function $\displaystyle f(z) = z\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{z}{n^2})exp({\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z^k}{k}})$. However, this diverges for large n because of the exponential term. What is the purpose of the exponential term and the canonical factors in this example?

If my solution or thinking is wrong, how would one go about creating an entire function that is zero at the positive squares?

Comment: On reading the title I got to thinking about $\sin(\pi x)$, which has simple zeros at all integers, and how to modify it to give simple zeros at only the positive integer squares.  But on reading the body of your post I suspect that may not be of much interest to you.

Comment: The order of each canonical factor in the product need not be $n$. That seems to be where you're going wrong.

Comment: Weierstrass factorization doesn't have the exponential term for your function since it is order $1/2$; it is just product on zeroes and for example can be written as $\sin \pi \sqrt z/(\pi \sqrt z)$ which is entire as writing the Taylor series easily shows